# providing auto Sugessions for android Google map palces

Tags: android, google-maps, search, google-places

I am very new to android Google maps i want provide the auto suggestions  in  the Google map places when ever user click on the Edittext in my program.supoose i entered H in the edit text the corresponding H related places display so that user can select the one place please help me how can i achieve this

Comment: Follow this link : http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-add-autocompletion-to-an-edittext

Comment: i want display place using placematrix api?

Answer (score 0):

this code is running in my apps :

MainActivity :-

```
mAtv_DestinationLocaiton = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_govia_destination_location);

mAtv_DestinationLocaiton.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                Log.i("Count", "" + count);
                if (!mAtv_DestinationLocaiton.isPerformingCompletion()) {
                    autocompletePlaceList.clear();
                    DestiClick2 = false;
                    new loadDestinationDropList().execute(s.toString());
                }
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    private class loadDestinationDropList extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
            destinationProgBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... unused) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            autocompletePlaceList = httpHelper
                    .getAutocompletePlaces(mAtv_DestinationLocaiton.getText()
                            .toString());

            return autocompletePlaceList;
        }
```

HttpHelper Class:-

```
public class HttpHelper {
    HttpManager httpCall;
    private static final String TAG = "GooglePlacesApi";
    private Context mContext;

    public HttpHelper(Context context) {

        mContext = context;
        httpCall = new HttpManager();
    }


        public ArrayList<String> getAutocompletePlaces(String placeName) {
        String response2 = "";
        ArrayList<String> autocompletPlaceList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String url = Constants.GOOGLE_PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_URL + "input="
                + placeName + "&sensor=false&key="
                + Constants.GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY;
        Log.e("MyAutocompleteURL", "" + url);

        try {
            response2 = httpCall.connectToGoogleServer(url);
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response2.trim()
                    .toString()).nextValue();
            JSONArray results = (JSONArray) jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                Log.e("RESULTS",
                        "" + results.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                autocompletPlaceList.add(results.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "description"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return autocompletPlaceList;
    }
    }
```

Comment: here ur using any jar files for connection of http ?

Comment: not using .jar file but using Google Direction Api for details

Comment: autocompletePlaceList what is this ?

Comment: ArrayList<String> autocompletePlaceList = new ArrayList<String>(); is a Arraylist to store autocomplite record

Comment: No Problem i remove some unnecessary code so just cut autocomplite  method in httphelper class ane paste main Activity.and use direct.its simple

Comment: response2 = httpCall.connectToGoogleServer(url); how can i call the manager?

Comment: please give suggestion so that i can forward thanks for ur help

Comment: response2 = httpCall.connectToGoogleServer(url);

Comment: it is the inatsance of the HttpManager class?

Comment: Just Copy getAutocompletePlaces method from httpHelper class n paste in Main Activity & delete HttpHelper class so you can direct call this methos like this  autocompletePlaceList =getAutocompletePlaces(mAtv_DestinationLocaiton.getText().toString());

Comment: thanks for ur valuable response but i have one dout with this GOOGLE_PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_UR ,GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY can i create constant for this two?

Comment: yes, i creat both in seprate file and here just bye name. i think easy and more easy way where ever call in project.

Comment: GOOGLE_PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_UR  can i know witch url ur using if u dont mind ?

Comment: i using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json? and if you like and my help useful so accept & upvote my answer

Comment: when i run the program it is showing progress bar when i type in edit text take as input when i am check in the  logcat it is taking but the output not displayed in the main program ?